# Getting current Quill Editor's toolbar background color

Tags: css, primeng, quill

I'm implementing a primeNg/quill editor, and as part of the UX design I need to display a container in the screen with the same color background as the editor's toolbar.  I'm looking at the snow.css file but can't seem to find it, any quill  experts know where I can find this on snow.css or any other dependent css of Quill? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toolbar background color in the PrimeNG Quill [demo](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor) is part of the [PrimeNG theme](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/resources/themes/omega/theme.css#L22) and not part of Quill's snow.css.

You can use the developer toolbar in Firefox and Chrome to see the CSS rules:

```
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    color: #1b1d1f;
    background: #f6f7f9 0 0 repeat-x;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f6f7f9 0%, #ebedf0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f6f7f9), color-stop(100%,#ebedf0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f6f7f9 0%,#ebedf0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f6f7f9 0%,#ebedf0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f6f7f9 0%,#ebedf0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #f6f7f9 0%,#ebedf0 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put inside a div with background color, and for editing area color use
Style backround color property.
below code for bootstrap and angular

```
    <div class="bg-light">
      <quill-editor [styles]="{height: '500px', backgroundColor: 'white'}">
      </quill-editor>
    </div>
```